# @google-cloud/bigquery Query API returning empty Promise when used in Cloud Function

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to use the '@google-cloud/bigquery' library to query BigQuery from a Google Cloud function. When the Promise returns, all I get back is an Array with another empty Array inside it, even though when I run the same query from the Big Query console I get a non-empty response back.

I've tried using an async function instead of a promise, but that was not successful. I also gave my Service Account "BigQuery Admin" and "Editor" privileges but that has not worked out either.

I do know the API is hitting Big Query. When I tried creating a new dataset from my Cloud Function, that call worked just fine, but for some reason I'm unable to get query results back from BQ.

```
  function warningAndPreventionIntent(agent) {
    let userCountry = agent.parameters['geo-country'];
    console.log(String(userCountry[0]));

    const gotCountry = userCountry.length > 0;

    if(gotCountry) {
      agent.add('Im looking into your trip');

      const OPTIONS = {
              query: 'SELECT disease.name FROM `projectId.dataset.table`, unnest(disease) disease WHERE country = @country',
              timeoutMs: 10000,
              useLegacySql: false,
              params: {country: userCountry[0]}
      };

      return bigquery
      .query(OPTIONS)
      .then(results => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(results[0]))
          const ROWS = results[0];

          let diseaseList = [];

          for(var row of ROWS) {
            diseaseList.push(row.name);
            console.log(diseaseList);
          }

          return true;

      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
      });
    }
  }
```

I should get a JSON `result` object with values, but I only get and array with an empty array `[[]]`

Comment: What happens if you hard code country in your code?  My thinking is to test a query by itself with minimal dependencies.

Comment: @Kolban thats something I thought about too, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. When I hard code the country I get the same response.

I've also tried querying a public dataset instead of my own and I still get no response.

Comment: FYI, I too was experiencing this same issue (a nodejs cloud function>bigquery returning empty array).  We too changed the package version (we upgraded to latest at the moment 4.1.2) and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Please find a working example using a public dataset you can use to test your query with

```
if (!global._babelPolyfill) {
    var a = require("babel-polyfill")
}

import BigQuery from '@google-cloud/bigquery'

describe('Check google-cloud', async () => {

    it('Test query', async () => {
        let result = await test('panada')

    })

    async function test(p1) {
        try {
            const bigquery = new BigQuery({
                projectId: `projectId`,
                keyFilename: '/Users/tamirklein/ssh/mydata.json'
            })

            let query = [
                'SELECT url',
                'FROM `publicdata.samples.github_nested`',
                'WHERE repository.owner = @owner'

            ].join(' ')

            console.log(`query is: ${query}`)
            let [result] = await bigquery.query({
                query,
                params: {
                    owner: p1
                }
            })

            result.forEach((row, index) => {
                console.log(`row number ${index}, url is: ${row.url}`)
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("err", err)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: It seems the google/bigquery version was my issue. When I downgraded back to 1.3.x my issue got resolved. Not sure if I'm using the new version incorrectly or if there's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

i am now getting the same thing.  I updated my cloud function without changing the code and the behavior changed.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please write a clear and useful answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Dan Wilson I fixed my issue by downgrading the google/bigquery dependency I was using to 1.3.x

It seems when I did an npm install I got upgraded the library to version 3 which wasn't working for me. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account your comments that downgrading google/bigquery to 1.3.X helped you resolve this. It seems to me that you may have been affected by [this Issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/issues/463). It looks like it was fixed in this [merge](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/pull/465), so you may be able to upgrade to the latest API version without re-introducing the error.