# BigQuery cannot return data that execute on cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

This function has been working normally, but when the latest was deployed to Cloud function, the value that returns from function is always empty and none error.
But if I run it in my local computer,it returns right value.

I don't know what is wrong. Help me please.

```
exports.fnGetCurrentLocationVehicle = function (sql) {<BR>
    let options = {<BR>
        query: sql,<BR>
        useLegacySql: false,<BR>
        useQueryCache: true<BR>
    }<BR>
    const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery'); <BR> 
    const bq = new BigQuery({projectId: projectId,}); <BR>
    return bq.query(options).then(function (data) {<BR>
           console.log({<BR>
                "fnGetCurrentLocationVehicle": options<BR>
            });<BR>
            var rows = data[0];<BR>
            return rows;<BR>
        })<BR>
        .catch(err => {<BR>
            if (err && err.name === 'PartialFailureError') {<BR>
                if (err.errors && err.errors.length > 0) {<BR>
                    console.log('Insert errors:');<BR>
                    err.errors.forEach(err => console.error(err));<BR>    
                }<BR>
            } else {<BR>
                oErr = 'ERROR:' + err;<BR>
                console.error('ERROR:', oErr);<BR>
            }<BR>
            throw err;<BR>
        });};
```

Comment: I suggest you check that you have an internet connection in your cloud environment.

Comment: Have you tried with rows = query_job.result()? 
https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/

Comment: FYI, I too was experiencing this same issue (a nodejs cloud function>bigquery returning empty array).  We changed the package version (we upgraded to latest at the moment 4.1.2) and the problem disappeared. See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334274/google-cloud-bigquery-query-api-returning-empty-promise-when-used-in-cloud-func